# Freeswitch update profile using mod_xml_curl

Tags: freeswitch

I am currently working on a project that updates profiles on a freeswitch server, using mod_xml_cur.

My problem is the following

My project is a selfhosted owin webapi that creates a profile and when requested uses owin to create an xml that should be loaded by freeswitch.

when i use the command "sofia profile test start" it fetches the profile(named test) from my owin url.

on the Console I see "Reload XML [succes]

but then it states [WARNING] sofia.c:5603 No Such Profile 'test'

the downloaded XML file is in /tmp with a temporary name .
And when I rename it and move it to /etc/freeswitch/sip_profiles#

and start it again, it loads the profile.

My understanding is that using mod_xml_curl the profile should load from memory when the xml is opened from my owin url.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you post the structure of the xml you are sending from your web service? I think the retrieved xml is consider invalid and the fallback xml is being loaded from your sip profile directory.

Comment: Problem is solved already. but thanks

Comment: In that case I suggest you answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
         <section name="configuration">
            <profiles>
                 <profile name="Your profile name">    
          <gateways>
          <gateway name="Your gateway name">  
        <param name="username" value="Your username"/>
       <settings>
```